# '%matplotlib inline' causes error in following code

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

If I comment out '%matplotlib inline' the code runs fine
But if I leave '%matplotlib inline' uncommented, 'fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=x_p, ncols=y_p)' starts to create blank plots, and following code triggers error as below. Any idea why?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, figures are closed at the end of a cell. This means that pyplot (`plt`) has forgotten about the axes to work on in the next cell.

```
%config InlineBackend
```

tells us:

> InlineBackend.close_figures= `<Bool>`
>       Current: *False*
>       Close all figures at the end of each cell.
>       When *True*, ensures that each cell starts with no active figures, but it also
>       means that one must keep track of references in order to edit or redraw
>       figures in subsequent cells. This mode is ideal for the notebook, where
>       residual plots from other cells might be surprising.
>       When *False*, one must call figure() to create new figures. This means that
>       gcf() and getfigs() can reference figures created in other cells, and the
>       active figure can continue to be edited with pylab/pyplot methods that
>       reference the current active figure.

The solution is thus to set `.close_figures` to False:

```
%config InlineBackend.close_figures=False
```

In order to prevent the automatic output of active figures at the end of a cell, you may then set `plt.ioff()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.close_figures=False
plt.ioff()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
```

[image]

Comment: `InlineBackend.close_figures` is deprecated/removed from IPython 3 onwards, am I right? And so the problem should disappear with the newer IPython?